# How to add my private key to my cert file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

As per official OpenSSL documentation [https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html\](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html%5C)

`-CAkey filename`
*Sets the CA private key to sign a certificate with. **If this option is not specified then it is assumed that the CA private key is present in the CA certificate file**.*

I have created a cert file using a private key as below:-

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out barneyCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key barneyCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out rootCA.pem
```

After this, I try to sign a csr without mentioning `-CAkey` and get an error as below:-

```
openssl x509 -req -in barney.test.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAcreateserial -out barney.test1.cer -days 825 -sha256 -extfile barney.text.ext
Signature ok
subject=/C=IN/ST=KA/L=BLR/O=CLDR/OU=SPRT/CN=SQDRN/emailAddress=rjindal@cloudera.com
Getting CA Private Key
unable to load CA Private Key
140344774555536:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

This is expected as my certificate `rootCA.pem` does not have the required private key yet.
If my understanding is correct, how do I add `barneyCA.key` to the `rootCA.pem`?

Comment: On Unix `cat barneyCA.key >>rootCA.pem` -- but then you can't safely give out the rootCA.pem to reliers, as you normally want to; safer `cat barneyCA.key rootCA.pem >combined` and use `combined` only in the CA for signing. On Windows `type key >>cert` or `copy cert combined & type key >>combined` (or `copy key+cert combined` and ignore the spurious 0x1A that gets added). Or of course just use `-CAkey` in the first place -- that's what it's there for.